# How to write a common propertie files for specific languages

Tags: tapestry

I am developing web application using tapestry. I have more than 15 tml files in my application. I am writing a properties files for German, English, French languages, for all the pages. In my all the pages, I have same footer, header and user authentication labels .

So I want to avoid writing separate properties file for all the pages and also minimize application memory size.

Please any one say how to write a common properties files for each language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try putting these common properties in `WEB-INF/app.properties`.